# Create a dict from a histogram - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am looking to create a json/dict from a histogram.

Loading data with `pandas` and plotting it results in the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)
df.hist(log=True)
```

Results in the following:
[image: Example histogram]

I am wondering what would be the best way to get this as a dict, I'm not strict about the way I want the dict to look like, but I'm thinking about something like

```
histogram = {
    'dropoff_latitude': {
        '30-35': 1800000,
        .....
    },
    'dropoff_longitude': {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just do `df.to_dict(orient=...)` in whatever orientation you want...

Comment: I think, he is asking about histogram plot's underlying data. Summary of it as dict.

Comment: I think you should use `np.histogram` to get values.

Comment: You need two edge values to define a bin. How would you represent that?

Comment: @IanS, well I would like to use exactly the bins that are generated by the `.hist` call, I believe that they are saved somewhere

Comment: @bluesummers `.hist` from pandas uses `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`, which in turn uses [`np.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), I believe.  The default number of bins there is 10.  And `np.histogram` returns a tuple of (`hist`, `bin_edges`).

Comment: @BradSolomon could be, obviously I want to preserve the flexibility of using things like `log=True` but essentially I believe that all the data that is needed to create the histogram is extractable from the returned value of `.hist()` call - I just don't know how

Comment: @bluesummers not sure if you will be able to go that route because pandas' `hist` just returnsmatplotlib [axes](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L2073).  I.e., the intermediate information you need is discarded locally within the function call.  (Not returned.)

Comment: @BradSolomon, that is a possibility too. I don't really know the underlying process of how the libraries interact with each other, but what I want to avoid is deciding the bins myself. I'm trying to get the exact same data that underlies the `.hist` call

Comment: "but what I want to avoid is deciding the bins myself".  The default bins in `pandas.hist` is 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way. `histfun` creates gets you the bins and count info from `np.histogram`. And, `label` creates the `bin` representation.

```
In [95]: def histfun(x):
    ...:     hist, bins = np.histogram(x)
    ...:     bbins = np.char.mod('%.2f', bins)
    ...:     label = map('-'.join, zip(bbins[:-1], bbins[1:]))
    ...:     return dict(zip(label, hist))
    ...:

In [96]: df.apply(histfun).to_dict()
Out[96]:
{'dropoff_latitude': {'30.00-35.00': 2,
  '35.00-40.00': 0,
  '40.00-45.00': 0,
  '45.00-50.00': 1,
  '50.00-55.00': 0,
  '55.00-60.00': 0,
  '60.00-65.00': 0,
  '65.00-70.00': 0,
  '70.00-75.00': 0,
  '75.00-80.00': 1},
 'dropoff_longitude': {'0.00-12.00': 2,
  '108.00-120.00': 1,
  '12.00-24.00': 0,
  '24.00-36.00': 0,
  '36.00-48.00': 0,
  '48.00-60.00': 0,
  '60.00-72.00': 1,
  '72.00-84.00': 0,
  '84.00-96.00': 0,
  '96.00-108.00': 0}}
```

Sample test data

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
   dropoff_latitude  dropoff_longitude
0                30                120
1                30                  0
2                45                  0
3                80                 60
```

Comment: This is great actually!
How would you accept basic things that go into histograms like `log=True`? `np.histogram` doesn't accept it

Comment: +1. Very consise solution. @bluesummers `log=True` refers to the plot, not the values, it thus makes no difference whether it is specified or not - the data will stay the same.

Comment: `log=True` is for visual representation, it's has nothing to do with `np.histogram` values, and mentioned above this comment too.